# PayPal webhook for recurring payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, webhooks, paypal-webhooks

I'm using ruby on rails and im trying to implement paypal webhooks so when a recurring payment occurs I get notified. I implemented a webhook with stripe and it was straight forward right from their API but i'm having trouble with paypal and their API isn't very helpful. Is there any good tutorial that I can look at for some help? Or is there anyone with their own example. Thank you for all the help.